# Can I Store my ehcache3.xml file in an external file

Tags: ehcache, urlclassloader, ehcache-3

In ehcache2, I stored my properties externally and read them using a input stream which was an available option for configuring this, but the same option isn't present in ehcache3.
ehcache2 code which works: https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/code-samples.html

Create a CacheManager from a configuration in an InputStream.

````
try {
  CacheManager manager = CacheManager.newInstance(fis);
} finally {
  fis.close();```

Is there any work around for the same in ehcache3?
````

Answer (score 0):

Ehcache3 doesn't have as straightforward a way of doing this as was present in ehcache2, but it definitely is possible.

You need to use the "import org.w3c.dom.Document" class and pass a Document to the XMLConfiguration constructor which you can use to build your cache manager:

`cacheManager = CacheManagerBuilder.newCacheManager(xmlConfiguration);`

The document itself is build like this:

```
      DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
      Document document = factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(inputStream);
      XMLConfiguration xmlConfiguration = new XMLConfiguration(document);
```

And now it should work.  You might have xml related errors, but otherwise, this should work perfectly normal if your xml is of the correct format.